# (B,N) pair and normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am trying to prove the following: Let $G$ be a finite group with a $(B,N)-$pair and assume that $B=UT$ with $U\triangleleft B$ and $U\cap T=1$. Let $\widetilde{G}\triangleleft G$ such that $U\le \widetilde{G}$ and set 
$$
\widetilde{B}=B\cap \widetilde{G},\widetilde{N}=N\cap \widetilde{G},\widetilde{T}=T\cap \widetilde{G},\widetilde{W}=\widetilde{N}/\widetilde{T}
$$
Then $\widetilde{G}$ has a $(B,N)$ pair given by $(\widetilde{B},\widetilde{N})$.

I have shown that $G=\widetilde{G}T$ and $N=\widetilde{N}T$, and that the inclusion $\widetilde{N}\hookrightarrow N$ induces an isomorphism $\widetilde{W}\simeq W$. 
I want to verify the last three axioms:

$(BN3)$: Let $w\in W$ and $s\in S$ ($S$ being a set of involutions generating $W$). Then $w\widetilde{B}s\subset \widetilde{B}ws\widetilde{B}\cup \widetilde{B}w\widetilde{B}$

$(BN4)$: Let $s\in S$. Then $\widetilde{B}^n\neq \widetilde{B}$ for any $n\in N$ that maps onto some $s\in S$.

$(BN5)$: The group $\widetilde{G}$ is generated by $\widetilde{B}$ and $\widetilde{N}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (BN5), we know that $G=BNB = UTNTU=UNU$ (since $T \le N$), and since $U \le \tilde{B}$, we get $\tilde{G}=\tilde{B}N\tilde{B} = \tilde{B}\tilde{N}\tilde{B}$.

You have not stated (BN4) correctly. You need to prove that $\tilde{B}^n \ne \tilde{B}$ for any $n \in N$ that maps onto some $s \in S$. Since $T \unlhd N$, $n$ normalizes $T$, so if if $n$ normalized $\tilde{B}$ then it would normalize $B = \tilde{B}T$, which it doesn't.

I haven't got time to think about (BN3) now.

Comment: Thanks very much Derek. I have amended my question regarding $(BN_4)$.